# java.lang.IllegalStateException exception occured in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jaas

I developed a simple web application using the following technologies JSF 2.0 , EJB 3, JPA and also JAAS for user login validation.

I structured my app in three projects: one is EJB project which contains the business and model, the second one is the view part of the project which is a Dynamic Web Project that includes ManagedBeans and JSF pages. And the last one is an EAR project which unite both projects.

Ear project was successfully deployed in JBoss 7 but when I try to access a page I get the following error:

```
21:04:29,671 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.jboss.msc.value.InjectedValue.getValue(InjectedValue.java:47)
at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction.setup(CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor.java:74)
at org.jboss.as.web.ThreadSetupBindingListener.bind(ThreadSetupBindingListener.java:50) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:125) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>ITSupportView</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/protected/user/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Protected area definition -->
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Area - ADMIN Only</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Restricted Area - USER and ADMIN</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/pages/protected/user/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>BASIC</role-name>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Login page -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/pages/public/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/pages/public/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- System roles -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>BASIC</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>CONS</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.itsupport.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/protected/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/protected/user/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>


<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msgs</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>


</faces-config>
```

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

I'm pretty newbie with these technologies so any advice would be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

---

Here is the full log. I noticed another error just before replacing the existing ear deployed file.

> Failure during stop of service
>   jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ITSupportView:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.ServletRewriteProvider.shutdown(Ljava/lang/Object;)V

```
15:04:43,872 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015009: Scan found incompletely copied file content for deployment d:\Programs\JBoss Server\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\ITSupportEAR.ear. Deployment changes will not be processed until all content is complete.
15:04:44,311 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'ITSupportEAR.ear/ITSupportModel.jar#ITSupportEJB'
15:04:44,324 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-3) RewriteFilter shutting down...
15:04:44,326 WARN  [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00004: Failure during stop of service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ITSupportView: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.ServletRewriteProvider.shutdown(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.destroy(RewriteFilter.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3989)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.stop(WebDeploymentService.java:108)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.stopService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1911) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1874) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

15:04:44,337 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] (MSC service thread 1-3) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ITSupportView].[jsp] has not been started
15:04:44,339 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] (MSC service thread 1-3) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ITSupportView].[default] has not been started
15:04:44,340 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase] (MSC service thread 1-3) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ITSupportView].[Faces Servlet] has not been started
15:04:44,341 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-3) RewriteFilter shutting down...
15:04:44,342 WARN  [org.jboss.msc] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00006: Uninjection "org.jboss.msc.service.ValueInjection@74c8cef2" of service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./ITSupportView failed unexpectedly: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.ServletRewriteProvider.shutdown(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.destroy(RewriteFilter.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:3301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3989)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebContextInjector.uninject(WebContextInjector.java:69)
    at org.jboss.msc.inject.CastingInjector.uninject(CastingInjector.java:60) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.uninject(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1919) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1893) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]

15:04:44,352 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011403: Stopping Persistence Unit Service 'ITSupportEAR.ear/ITSupportView.war#ITSupportEJB'
15:04:44,361 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ITSupportModel.jar in 61ms
15:04:44,361 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ITSupportService.jar in 61ms
15:04:44,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ITSupportView.war in 295ms
15:04:44,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ITSupportEAR.ear in 300ms
15:04:44,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ITSupportEAR.ear"
15:04:44,644 WARN  [org.jboss.metadata.parser.jboss.JBossAppMetaDataParser] (MSC service thread 1-1) loader-repository element in jboss-app.xml is deprecated and has been ignored
15:04:45,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ITSupportView.war"
15:04:45,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ITSupportService.jar"
15:04:45,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ITSupportModel.jar"
15:04:47,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ITSupportEJB
15:04:47,042 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultAnnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
15:04:47,044 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
15:04:47,050 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for ITSupportEJB
15:04:47,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserDAO in deployment unit subdeployment "ITSupportService.jar" of deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportService/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:app/ITSupportService/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:module/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportService/UserDAO
    java:app/ITSupportService/UserDAO
    java:module/UserDAO

15:04:47,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-3) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserFacadeImpl in deployment unit subdeployment "ITSupportService.jar" of deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportService/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:app/ITSupportService/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:module/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportService/UserFacadeImpl
    java:app/ITSupportService/UserFacadeImpl
    java:module/UserFacadeImpl

15:04:47,153 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserFacadeImpl in deployment unit subdeployment "ITSupportView.war" of deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportView/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:app/ITSupportView/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:module/UserFacadeImpl!com.itsupport.facade.UserFacade
    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportView/UserFacadeImpl
    java:app/ITSupportView/UserFacadeImpl
    java:module/UserFacadeImpl

15:04:47,157 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-2) JNDI bindings for session bean named UserDAO in deployment unit subdeployment "ITSupportView.war" of deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportView/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:app/ITSupportView/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:module/UserDAO!com.itsupport.dao.UserDAO
    java:global/ITSupportEAR/ITSupportView/UserDAO
    java:app/ITSupportView/UserDAO
    java:module/UserDAO

15:04:47,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'ITSupportEAR.ear/ITSupportModel.jar#ITSupportEJB'
15:04:47,237 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ITSupportEJB
    ...]
15:04:47,310 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
15:04:47,319 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
15:04:47,332 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
15:04:47,334 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
15:04:47,474 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
15:04:47,479 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'ITSupportEAR.ear/ITSupportView.war#ITSupportEJB'
15:04:47,480 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ITSupportEJB
    ...]
15:04:47,510 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
15:04:47,514 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
15:04:47,516 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
15:04:47,518 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
15:04:47,534 INFO  [org.hibernate.search.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 4.1.0.Alpha1
15:04:47,557 WARN  [org.hibernate.search.impl.ConfigContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) HSEARCH000075: Configuration setting hibernate.search.lucene_version was not specified, using LUCENE_CURRENT.
15:04:47,663 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
15:04:47,677 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
15:04:47,738 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/ITSupportView'
15:04:47,993 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-7-thread-1) Unable to access url jndi:/default-host/ITSupportView/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml.  Monitoring for this resource will no longer occur.
15:04:48,056 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewritePhaseListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) RewritePhaseListener starting up.
15:04:48,919 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
15:04:48,920 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Monitoring jndi:/default-host/ITSupportView/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
15:04:48,922 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) RewriteFilter starting up...
15:04:48,938 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [4] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RewriteLifecycleListener [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRewriteLifecycleListener<-100>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.FacesRewriteLifecycleListener<0>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.DefaultRewriteLifecycleListener<2147483647>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.lifecycle.JoinRewriteLifecycleListener<2147483647>]
15:04:48,941 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestCycleWrapper [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteRequestCycleWrapper<0>]
15:04:48,942 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RewriteProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.DefaultHttpRewriteProvider<0>]
15:04:48,943 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RewriteResultHandler [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpRewriteResultHandler<0>]
15:04:48,944 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.InboundRewriteProducer [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpInboundRewriteProducer<0>]
15:04:48,946 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.OutboundRewriteProducer [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.HttpOutboundRewriteProducer<0>]
15:04:48,948 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.ContextListener [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyConfigContextListener<0>]
15:04:48,950 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestListener []
15:04:48,951 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.spi.RequestParameterProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRequestParameterProvider<0>]
15:04:48,954 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.el.spi.ExpressionLanguageProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.FacesExpressionLanguageProvider<30>]
15:04:48,956 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.InvocationResultHandler [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.NavigatingInvocationResultHandler<100>]
15:04:48,958 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.common.spi.ServiceEnricher []
15:04:48,960 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [1] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.ConfigurationCacheProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.ServletContextConfigurationCacheProvider<0>]
15:04:48,963 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [2] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationProvider [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.config.AnnotationConfigProvider<100>, org.ocpsoft.rewrite.prettyfaces.PrettyFacesRewriteConfigurationProvider<1>]
15:04:48,969 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.DefaultHttpRewriteProvider] (MSC service thread 1-1) Loaded [0] org.ocpsoft.rewrite.spi.RuleCacheProvider []
15:04:48,989 INFO  [org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter] (MSC service thread 1-1) Rewrite 2.0.0.Alpha5 initialized.
15:04:48,991 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /ITSupportView
15:04:49,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018565: Replaced deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear" with deployment "ITSupportEAR.ear"
15:06:22,966 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.jboss.msc.value.InjectedValue.getValue(InjectedValue.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.processors.CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor$CachedConnectionManagerSetupAction.setup(CachedConnectionManagerSetupProcessor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.web.ThreadSetupBindingListener.bind(ThreadSetupBindingListener.java:50) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:125) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: is it a full log? Please provide more. There must be more info.

Comment: @MironBalcerzak thanks for your quick reply. I just added the full log and noticed another error arises when ear file is replaced. Also another issue that i've found was the web content from my war file was not deployed, so I moved all this content in my webapp folder and after a second deploy these files were successfully deployed as well.

Comment: just as you have noticed in the log - there's a missing library in your deplyoment ear. check whether you have it packaged in your lib dir or not - if not, update your pom.xml - should do the trick :)